# cant get Regex to work (.NET) without a space in text

Tags: regex-group

im trying to split a series of lines based on the LAST underscore character.

its something to do with that one line not having a space in the text & im not familiar with regex concepts like lookahead and lookbehind

using

```
^(.*?)_(\w+?)*$
```

run against

```
2022-366_DA00_Cover Sheet_C
2022-366_DA01_Locality Plan_E
2022-366_DA02_Site Plan_H
2022-366_DA03_Delivery Plan_E
2022-366_DA04_Floorplan_D
2022-366_DA05_Roof Plan_D
2022-366_DA06_Front  Side Building Elevations_F
2022-366_DA07_Drivethru  Rear Building Elevations_D
2022-366_DA08_External Finishes Schedule_A
```

produces

```
2022-366_DA00_Cover Sheet==C
2022-366_DA01_Locality Plan==E
2022-366_DA02_Site Plan==H
2022-366_DA03_Delivery Plan==E
**2022-366==D**
2022-366_DA05_Roof Plan==D
2022-366_DA06_Front  Side Building Elevations==F
2022-366_DA07_Drivethru  Rear Building Elevations==D
2022-366_DA08_External Finishes Schedule==A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to repeat the capture group as you want to match 1 or more word characters (also if you use `*` then the whole group could also be optional)

Matching the word characters `\w+?` and the `.*?` do not have to be non greedy.

If you want to match a single uppercase char A-Z you could also use `[A-Z]` instead of `\w+`

You might write the pattern excluding matching an underscore from the word characters:

```
^(.*)_([^\W_]+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*)` Capture **group 1**, match the whole line
- `_` Match `_`
- `([^\W_]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ word chars except for `_`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xUd60Z/1)

Comment: although this is working, I don't think the wording on the second group is the best solution. The underscore match should always match to the last occurrence. So I guess there is no need to explicitly exclude the underscore. And as there is no need for this, I would say it is more readable if you don't do it like this, especially as the ^\W part is easily misunderstood.

Comment: @roediGERhard The second group using `([^\W_]+)` is the solution to matching word characters without an underscore, as the OP intended to match word characters but `\w ` also matches an underscore.

Comment: I did understand what you intended to do, but as mentioned I don't think it is necessary to exclude the underscore due to the greediness of the underscore match itself. So if there is an underscore in the input string, the regex would match the "_" to the last occurring underscore. Therefore every following sequence is per definition without any underscore and therefore the exclusion of the underscore in the last part is not needed, as there can never be an underscore in this sequence.

Comment: @roediGERhard the `.+` or the dot for that matter can be tricky. If you use `.+` instead of `.*` you can see that last match in this demo is not correct as the dot with the quantifier allows backtracking.  https://regex101.com/r/uAEPGH/1 If you use `.*` it can match a trailing `_` That is why matching after the last `_` you should be more specific depending on what you want to allow to match. You could for example also use `^(.*)_([^_]+)$` to not allow underscores to the end :-) https://regex101.com/r/66RFGe/1

Comment: now I see what you want to achieve. You do not want to match at all, as there is a trailing underscore. OK, in this case I'd go with the solution in your comment `^(.*)_([^_]+)$`. Depending on the relevance of "loosing" a line without further actions this can be a way(as there is no distinction between a halfway proper line, just missing the last part and a completely different line). Otherwise, as it is relevant to get noticed about such lines I'd go and check the line in two steps for general match and value extraction.

Comment: more testing my end i have ended up with  `^(.*)[._-]([^._-]+)$`   that works with the current cases I have.

Comment: @RobG That is another way to write it, so you want to match either `.` `_` `-` followed by 1 or more characters that are not one of those?

Comment: actually only want dash and underscore, so will try dropping the dot from the separator section.

Answer (score 0):

that:

```
^(.?)_(\w+?)$
```

does not seem right to me, as there is this additional quantifier on the second group? Furthermore I don't think you want the '?' quantifier on either of those groups. Here is what I read from your regex:

```
^     ... start of the line
(...) ... first group
.?    ... every character matches(.), if there is exactly zero or one of them(?)
_     ... match an underscore(due to default greedy matching, this will match on the last underscore)
(...) ... second group
\w+?  ... any word character will match if there is one or more of them. the question mark is too much, as there can only be one quantifier.
$     ... end of the line
```

here is what I would have tried using:

```
^(.*)_(.*)$
```

which translates to:

```
^     ... start of the line
(...) ... first group
.*    ... match every character (.) if there is any (*)
_     ... matches the last(remember the greedy thing) underscore
(...) ... second group
.*    ... match every character if there is any
$     ... end of the line
```

this should bring the needed information stored after the last matching underscore.

Comment: This is not the pattern `^(.?)_(\w+?)$` Also using `^(.*)_(.*)$` matches a trailing underscore as `.*` is optional.

Comment: I see the problem with the trailing underscore. It is up to the OP on how to handle this issue. One could alter the last matching group to (.+) in order to make sure to not get an empty result. One could also check for the trailing underscore beforehand and act completely different.